# How far is it from the equator to the north pole if you keep going northeast?

Tags: spheres

You may simplify Earth as a sphere with 40 Mm circumference.

I thought about it when I read the Mercator projection has straight lines for constant bearing courses. You'd spiral around the north pole infinite times, and the line on the Mercator projection is infinite, but I suspect the actual distance is finite. I haven't tried to calculate that at all.

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried? Where does this question come from?

Comment: @Christoph I thought about it when I read the Mercator projection has straight lines for constant bearing courses. You'd spiral around the north pole infinite times, and the line on the Mercator projection is infinite, but I suspect the actual distance is finite. I haven't tried to calculate that at all.

Comment: Please add this information (your response to Christoph) to the body of the question, by clicking the tiny `edit`. Otherwise this post is likely to be closed due to lack of context via community votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a sphere of radius $1$ centered at the origin in $\mathbb R^3$, you get a curve
\begin{align*}
x(t) &= \frac{\cos t}{\sqrt{\sinh^2 t + 1}}, \\
y(t) &= \frac{\sin t}{\sqrt{\sinh^2 t + 1}}, \\
z(t) &= \frac{\sinh t}{\sqrt{\sinh^2 t + 1}}, \\
\end{align*}
with time $t\in[0,\infty)$.

This curve has finite length
$$
L = \int_0^\infty \sqrt{\dot x(t)^2+\dot y(t)^2+\dot z(t)^2}\,\mathrm dt = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt 2}.
$$

Multiply by the radius of the earth to obtain the real length of the trip.

Comment: Ok, so that's 14,153 km instead of the direct  10,000 km. thanks. A general answer (any angle, any starting point) would trump this simple and elegant answer.